# Extract information from contingency table in R

Tags: r

This is a very basic question, but I have this workflow:

```
* Create decision tree using `rpart`
* Generate prediction using `predict`
* Generate the contingency table using `table`
```

When I run this and `print(cTable)` I get the result:

```
predict10f.ds1
     1  2  3
  2  0 18  0
```

I don't understand what I'm looking at. How do I extract the individual values from cTable?

Comment: you mean `unname(cTable)`?

Comment: What is the (first) variable used to build this table? It looks like the output of `predict` is all `2`'s and there are `18` of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is displaying the frequency of items in your predict object for value 2, no  predictions of 1 or 3, and 18 predictions for 2.